# How to merge cherry-picked revisions between feature branches and trunk

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

I have two feature branches derived from the trunk, both involving big code reorganisation in different modules, Feature-A and Feature-B. Both are kept in sync with the trunk; the trunk is required to be stable.

Half-way through working on Feature-B, I realise that a change to a shared library recently implemented on Feature-A would greatly benefit Feature-B. I do not yet want to put this change in the trunk, and I cannot fully merge the branches because the rest of the code on Feature-A is not stable.

So do a merge between branches, cherry-picking revisions from A to B, to only merge this feature:

svn merge -r 1786:1795 ^/proj/branches/Feature-A .

I cannot figure out if I will get in trouble later when I re-integrate branches. I expect Feature-B to be finished a lot sooner than Feature-A. At that point our normal procedure would be to re-integrate feature-B into the trunk, and then merge trunk into feature-A to keep those in sync. I have difficulty figuring out in advance if this will cause conflict, seeing as A was merged into B, and now those changes are getting re-merged back but in a roundabout way, via the trunk.

svn book mentions that an extra merge with --record-only after re-integrating branch into trunk, if I want to be able to work on the branch again. I suspect that I may need something like that in this situation, but I cannot work out if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't use `--reintegrate` with long term feature branches.

In your case you could merge Feature-B branch back to trunk normaly, and then, before you merge Feature-B back to trunk, do `--record-only` to the problematic revision:

Suppose that the command:

```
svn merge -r 1786:1795 ^/proj/branches/Feature-A .
```

created the revision 2000 (in branch Feature-B).

Then, before merging Feature-B back to trunk you must do:

```
svn merge -c2000 --record-only ^/proj/branches/Feature-B .
```

The last step is doing the complete merge of Feature-B branch to trunk:

```
svn merge -r <begin>:<end> ^/proj/branches/Feature-B .
```

Comment: Would this really work without --reintegrate, given that I have been doing regular merges from trunk to Feature-B? My understanding is that if I tried to do a merge without reintegrate, I would get a whole bunch of conflicts because of the changes to the trunk that have been duplicated to the branch.

Answer (score 0):

This will indeed cause you problems.

If the changes you merge from A to B include additional files then when you reintegrate B those files will be added to trunk. But then if you attempt to merge from trunk to A (which you will need to do prior to reintegrating A) then the merge will attempt to re-add those files to A which already exist in A, causing a tree conflict.

A --record-only merge is used to block the re-merging of specific revisions to keep a feature branch alive after reintegration. So if you reintegrate B into trunk creating revision 100, then you --record-only merge trunk revision 100 back to B, this means that when you do a sync merge in B from trunk (svn merge ^/Project1/trunk) revision 100 will be skipped and not remerged back to B. This avoids the potential conflict and enables the feature branch to continue to be used and resynced with trunk after reintegration.

Unfortunately I don't think a --record-only merge can help you avoid the conflict in your situation, because a reintegrate merge doesn't examine the individual revisions in the branch to be merged, it just does a diff of the current state of the branch and trunk and applies that to the trunk working copy.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful clarification, I see where a tree conflict would happen.